# Asynchronous file reading, cannot make function finish before returning

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to read all files in folder, check if it has `featured: true` prop, increase the counter if it does and then throw error if there is more than 1 such file. But for some reason, my code doesn't wait and simply jumps to last section, this is the output

```
this should be last
Inside item, looking for featured prop
Inside item, looking for featured prop
```

My code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const findInDir = require('./utils/findInDir');

(async () => {
  const dir = './public/page-data/blog';
  const fileRegex = /.*/;
  const allFiles = findInDir(dir, fileRegex);
  let result = 0;

  await allFiles.map(file => {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      const obj = JSON.parse(data);

      if (obj.result.pageContext.featured === true) {
        console.log('Inside item, looking for featured prop');
        result += 1;
      }
    });
  });

  console.log('this should be last');

  if (result > 1) {
    throw new Error('There are multiple featured blog posts, please fix.');
  }
})();
```

Need some help understanding what am I doing wrong.

Comment: `map` isn't an async function. Nor are you returning anything from it.

Comment: `.map()` does not return a Promise, so awaiting it is useless

Comment: And `fs.readFile` also does not create a promise, nor do you convert it to a promise that is returned from `.map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the non-callback version of `fs.readFile` in order to actually `await` reading the file. Also using `.map` does not make a lot of sense as you're not actually mapping something, so simply use a `for .. of` loop:

```
for (const file of allFiles){
 try {
   const data = await fs.promises.readFile(file);
   // ...
 } catch(err) {
   // handle error
 }
}

console.log('this should be last');
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

```
(async () => {
  const dir = "./public/page-data/blog";
  const fileRegex = /.*/;
  const allFiles = findInDir(dir, fileRegex);

  try {
    await Promise.all(
      allFiles.map((file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          fs.readFile(file, "utf8", (err, data) => {
            const obj = JSON.parse(data);

            if (obj.result.pageContext.featured === true) {
              reject("Inside item, looking for featured prop");
            } else {
              resolve();
            }
          });
        });
      })
    );
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("There are multiple featured blog posts, please fix.");
  }
})();
```

Instead of checking every item one by one like in an loop i do it like this. It checks "parallel" if any of them has `featured` set to true. Therefore its faster then a loop

If its `true` i reject it and the `Promise.all()` stops. The `try / catch` of the `Promise.all()` catches the rejection

---

You need to understand just 1 thing to know when to use `await` and when not.

It only makes sense to use `await` on promises.

How do you know if its an promise? Just `console.log` it

Does it console log `Promise`? Use `await`

Does it NOT console log `Promise`? It makes no sense to use `await`

[image]

This returns just an array. Does it makes sense to use `await`? No, it does not return an `Promise`

But if you do it like this:

[image]

You have an array of promises.
Here is a bit different. You have an array BUT the elements inside are an promise.
You can use `Promise.all()` it basically awaits for every item in the array until its done.